# There is an iframe tag covering whole page preventing interaction with the app

Tags: html, reactjs, iframe

I am working on a web app which another developer has developed. Every time I run the project or refresh the page, an empty iframe covers the entire screen and other HTML elements are not shown in elements section of inspect. In order to interact with the app I have to delete it from inspect. I could not find the code snippet related to the iframe in the project. May anybody help me to solve this problem?

`<iframe style="position: fixed; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; border: none; z-index: 2147483647;"></iframe>`

Comment: Can you ask that other developer?

Comment: @lupz Actually I am not in contact with him, and I think he did this on purpose to mess up the project.

Comment: Maybe he added it as a "security" feature to prevent users from accessing some site contents?

Comment: @johey Maybe. How do they add such a security feature?

Comment: It could be located somewhere in the source code. Or it could be added by a server module or even a network appliance (e.g. a proxy server).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding this to your CSS:

```
iframe {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

The pointer-events property allows for control over how HTML elements respond to mouse/touch events – including CSS hover/active states, click/tap events in Javascript, and whether or not the cursor is visible.

None prevents all click, state and cursor options on the specified HTML element

Or

```
iframe {
  display: none;
}
```